# How to redirect logged users to a custom page in buddypress & wordpress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am trying too redirect every logged users to a specific page of their profile...See this example page..
this site is build on wp and bp. I am using BP Profile as Homepage plugin for logged in user redirection...
this see this code ...

```
function bp_profile_homepage()
{
   global $bp;
   $selected_role = get_option('bpahp_role_choice');
   if($selected_role == '')
   {
       if(is_user_logged_in() && bp_is_front_page())
       {
            wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain );
       }
   }
   else
   {
       if(!current_user_can($selected_role) && bp_is_front_page())
       {

            wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain );
       }
   }
}
```

So after using this plugin i am able to redirect my user to their profile page automatically when they logged in..
http://www.example.com/members/admin/

but i want to redirect them to this page

http://www.example.com/members/admin/activity/all-activity/

All activity is a sub page of activity directory in which i am showing all activities to users sitewide..
i do not want to send them on site wide activity page for seeing activity i want to show them all that on their profile page..

So any idea what to add in this code
   wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain );

to make it workable with my requirement....
I have tried so many tricks for making my requirement workable but do not get success..i have also tried to replace this code

```
wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain );
```

with this one...
    $redirect_url = "$bp->loggedin_user->domain/activity/all-activity/";
            wp_redirect( $redirect_url );

And this one

```
$redirect_url = "activity/all-activity/";   
    wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain/$redirect_url );
```

Nothing is working
Please somebody help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

`wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain . '/activity/all-activity/' );`

Comment: Your solution is not working properly.. I am it is redirecting logged in user to http://www.example.com/members/admin/activity/all-activity/ but ... if user is not logged in and he is trying to open homepage of the website so it is redirecting him to http://www.example.com/activity/all-activity/ page which is not created in my website so it is giving 404 error..

Comment: Add an `if( is_user_logged_in() )` before the redirect statement. Also don't forget to `exit;`, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: just see the above rewritten code..I am already using it bro..   if(is_user_logged_in() && bp_is_front_page())

Comment: i think the problem is if a user is not logged so it is still running that php code for checking it and then bcoz it is using wp_redirect so it is just using . '/activity/all-activity/' this line as a redirection value..bcoz he does not get any value for $bp->loggedin_user->domain . for a unlogged user..

Comment: Ok, just start the code of your function with: `if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;`

Comment: Yes you are right..I got it now it is working as per your direction i did some changes in the code..see this if( is_user_logged_in() )
   {
   wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain.'activity/all-activity/' );
   }
   else 
   {
   wp_redirect( $bp->loggedin_user->domain );
   } and now it is working perfectly.. thanks for the suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

Below code is used to redirect the use to buddypress profile page after login

```
function bp_help_redirect_to_profile(){
  global $bp;
  if( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {
   bp_core_redirect( get_option('home') . '/members/' . 
   bp_core_get_username( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) . '/profile' );
  }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'bp_help_redirect_to_profile',1);
```